# How does Python's re-declaration of variables work internally?

Tags: python, variables

I'm fairly new to Python so this might seem like a trivial question to some. But I'm curious about how Python works internally when you bind a new object to a variable, referring to the previous object bound to the same variable name. Please see the code below as an example - I understand that python breaks the bond with the original object 'hello', bind it to the new object, but what is the sequence of events here? how does python break the bond with the original object but also refer to it?

```
greeting = 'hello'
greeting = f'y{greeting[1:len(greeting)]}'
```

In addition to the explanation, I would also very much appreciate some contexts. I understand that strings are immutable but what about other types like floats and integers?
Does it matter whether I understand how python operates internally? Also, where would be a good place to learn more about how Python works internally if it does?

Hope I'm being clear with my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation through the medium of the disassembly:

```
>>> dis.dis('''greeting = 'hello'
... greeting = f'y{greeting[1:len(greeting)]}'
... ''')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (greeting)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('y')
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (greeting)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (len)
             12 LOAD_NAME                0 (greeting)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 BUILD_SLICE              2
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             22 BUILD_STRING             2
             24 STORE_NAME               0 (greeting)
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

The number on the far left indicates where the bytecode for a particular line begins. Line 1 is pretty self-explanatory, so I'll explain line 2.

As you might notice, your f-string doesn't survive compilation; it becomes a bunch of raw opcodes mixing the loading of constant segments with the evaluation of formatting placeholders, eventually leading to the stack being topped by all the fragments that will make up the final string. When they're all on the stack, it then puts all the fragments together at the end with `BUILD_STRING 2` (which says "Take the top two values off the stack and combine them into a single string").

`greeting` is just a name holding a binding. It doesn't actually hold a value, just a reference to whatever object it's currently bound to. And the original reference is pushed onto the stack (with `LOAD_NAME`) entirely before the `STORE_NAME` that pops the top of the stack and rebinds `greeting`.

In short, the reason it works is that the value of `greeting` is no longer needed by the time it's replaced; it's used to make the new string, then discarded in favor of the new string.

Answer (score 0):

In your second line, Python evaluates the right side of the assignment statement, which creates a string that uses the old binding for `greeting`. Only after evaluating that expression does it handle the assignment operator, which binds that string to the name.  It's all very linear.

Floats and integers are also immutable.  Only lists and dictionaries are mutable.  Actually, it's not clear how you would modify an integer object in any case.  You can't refer to the inside of the object.  It's important to remember that in this case:

```
i = 3
j = 4
i = i + j
```

the last line just creates a new integer/float object and binds it to `i`.  None of this attempts to modify the integer object `3`.

I wrote this article that tries to delineate the difference between Python objects and the names we use:

https://github.com/timrprobocom/documents/blob/main/UnderstandingPythonObjects.md